# Query for first result in a column - substring_index function - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to get the substring_index() to work:

I have created a simple table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ContactList(
cont_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
last_name varchar(30),
first_name varchar(20),
interests varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY(cont_id));
```

I then populated the ContactList table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ContactList (last_name, first_name, interests)
VALUES 
('Murphy', 'Dave', 'Golf, Pets, Basketball'),
('Murphy', 'Ben', 'Pets, Gym, Basketball'),
('Finn', 'Belinda', 'Pets, Tennis, Knitting'),
('Murphy', 'Steve', 'Pets, Archery, Fishing');
```

I ran a quick SELECT to ensure the data was entered correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM ContactList;
```

Then I ran the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ContactList
WHERE last_name = 'Murphy'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(interests, ',' ,1) = 'Pets';
```

I was expecting to get two records back (which I did for Ben & Steve), however, for the 'Interests' column I was assuming I should only get one interest back if it equaled 'pets' (due to the substring_index) however, I got all interests back.  How can I use the SUBSTRING_INDEX() to run the query and only get the first interest listed back for each record if it says 'Pets'?

BTW I am using MySQL Version 5.5.24 and I know the Interests would be best suited in their own table - I just want to see why substring_index is not picking the first item from the list if it equals 'pets'.

Thanks for any input,

Andy R ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in the `WHERE` clause, which determines which *rows* to include. That's good, but you also need to use it in the `SELECT` clause, which determines which *columns* to include.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  last_name,
  first_name,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(interests, ',' ,1) AS FirstInterestInList
FROM ContactList
WHERE last_name = 'Murphy'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(interests, ',' ,1) = 'Pets';
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the reply.  It works.  I am not sure that I would have worked this out on my own and I was trying all sorts ;-) Thanks again, Andy R.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! In general, you have to specify which table columns (or expressions) you want in your results, and `SELECT *` means "all the columns". Try these examples verbatim and you'll get the idea: `SELECT last_name FROM ContactList`, `SELECT last_name, 'a string constant' FROM ContactList`, `SELECT first_name, 1+2+3, UPPER(last_name) FROM ContactList`, `SELECT first_name, interests, CURDATE() FROM ContactList`. The fact that you were able to figure out `SUBSTRING_INDEX` tells me you'll figure this out no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Although `substring_index()` will work for the first element, you really want `find_in_list()`:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(interests, ',' ,1) AS FirstInterestInList
FROM ContactList
WHERE last_name = 'Murphy' and
      find_in_set('pets', interests) = 1
```

The advantage of `find_inset()` is that it will work for arbitrary positions.

Just as a note, though, your delimiter is `', '`.  For `find_in_set()` to work best, you should have no space after the column.

Also, if you are doing queries like this, you should fix your data structure.  It really wants a table called something like `ContactInterests` which contains one row for each contact and each interest.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon I will try this out.  Your explanation is super, Andy ;-)